# Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra 6.7 Exercise 7

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra 6.7 Exercise 6 is following.

6. Let $A$ be the $4 \times 4$ matrix in Example 6 of Section 6.3. Find matrices $E_1, E_2, E_3$ such that $A = c_1E_1 + c_2E_2 + c_3E_3$, $I = E_1 + E_2 + E_3$ and $E_i E_j = 0, i \ne j$.

Section 6.3 doesn't have Example 6. Last example of Section 6.3 is Example 5. The $4 \times 4$ matrix in Example 5 of Section 6.3 is following.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

My answer is $c_1 = 0, c_2 = -2, c_3 = 2$ and

$$E_1 = \frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, E_2 = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 & 2 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 & -2 & 2 \\ 2 & -2 & 2 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 & -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, E_3 = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

And exercise 7 is following.

7. In Exercises 5 and 7, notice that (for each $i$) the space of eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue $c_i$ is spanned by the column vectors of the various matrices $E_j$ with $j \ne i$. Is that a coincidence?

I found that $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $0$ in exercise 6 which is not a linear combination of column vectors of $E_2$ and $E_3$.

Is this exercise wrong or I made any mistake?